# SharePoint 2007 - library with list items

Tags: list, document-library, content-type

For an application that I'm working on, we have two separate content types - one based on Item and one based on Document.  I'd like to create a container that houses both of these content types.

I know it is possible to use a Data View web part to see the items of a list and documents of a library in one place, but this requires a separate list and library.  What I'd really like is one container to hold both types.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A list can include files as attachments, but I'm not sure if you can associate a content type based on the Document content type with a list.  In cases where the question of "is it a list or a library" came up, I've always answered that by asking if there "would always be a list?" and here the answer is no.

Give a list a try and perhaps rebuild the one content type if needed.